# IOS memory management object issue in Appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have a Property in my AppDelegate as follows

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *viewController;
```

This viewController is now retained.

Now i have another Class called StateClass, during which i make some transitions

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NewController *mycontrol = [[NewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *tempcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mycontrol];

appDelegate.viewController= mycontrol;


if (appDelegate.viewController==nil)
{
DDLogInfo(@"appdelegate viewController is null");
}
```

It is sometimes printing it out as null and some times it works, i am stuck with this problem can any body pull in and help me please

Comment: it works normally,within the appdelegate, but in the state class i have found this problem, any specific reason that the memory pointed could be released anyway?

Comment: Show the code for `NewController`. Have you debugged to check each line?

Comment: The new controller is nothing but a UIViewController, i have simply subclassed it and there is nothing much left there. yes Indeed the app works normally using the same way, but during some transition later this happens